# Denwer и file_get_contents

Tags: php.ini, php, denwer, https, синтаксический-анализ

В сети много записей о проблемах **`Denwer`** и **`file_get_contents`** при **`https`**, но, увы, нет толкового ответа.

Пишем:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/oauth/access_token?сlient_id='.CLIENT_ID.'&code='.$_REQUEST['code'].'&client_secret='.SECRET), true);
```

Получаем: **`Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?`**

Как лечить больного? Желательно не народной медициной, а написав рецепты с конкретными лекарствами. **`:-)`**

**`extension=php_openssl.dll`** — стоит. **`Денвер`** — последняя версия.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как вылечить проблему с openssl в Denwer-е:

1. Удостоверимся, что рабочим конфигом является тот, который будем проверять (по умолчанию это `php.ini`) — можно воспользоваться ф-цией [php_ini_loaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php).
2. Проверяем, что в этом конфигурационном ini-файле есть строка `extension=php_openssl.dll`, и что она не закомментирована.
3. Проверяем наличие файла `%PHP_DIR%/ext/php_openssl.dll`. Если такового нет, то идем [сюда](http://www.denwer.ru/packages/php5.html) и качаем дополнение. В состав этого пакета входит недостающий `php_openssl.dll`. Делаем бекап файла `php.ini`, тушим Денвер и устанавливаем пакет расширения.
4. Удостоверимся, что инсталлятор не изменил файл `php.ini`. Скорее всего, изменил.

   - Редактируем «обновленный» `php.ini`, снова включая строку `extension=php_openssl.dll`
   - или восстанавливаем `php.ini` из бекапа.
5. Перезапускаем Денвер.

Проверяем:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
$file = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/');
die($file);

?>
```

А вообще, прекратите юзать денвер. Ставьте vbox, на него линух, потом nginx, который достаточно легко настраивается. Это я не думал с 13-го года, это я просто забыл ответ обновить. Debian wheezy+nginx+php+fpm (+до X модулей из пакетов) за час-два. Не бойтесь перемен ;)

Answer (score 0):

did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP.
Ясно написано: "Вы забыли его включить в настройках php"
php.ini открывай и включай

Comment: extension=php_openssl.dll — стоит. Ок да? :)

Comment: ;extension=php_openssl.dll
вот так, да?

Comment: ; — это же комментарий.

Comment: Тогда могу предложить лишь сменить денвер на что нибудь другое

Comment: `Желательно не народной медициной, а написав рецепты с конкретными лекарствами. :-)`

Comment: Можно еще использовать curl, он отлично работает с https.

А если проблема не в ";extension=php_openssl.dll", то это уже точно с денвером что то.

Comment: А можно на деле?
Есть ссылка:

    https://api.vk.com/oauth/access_token?сlient_id='.CLIENT_ID.'&code='.$_REQUEST['code'].'&client_secret='.SECRET

Как её парсить и приравнять к переменой ответы?

Comment: А сама dll-ка есть? А то, с денвером она, по-моему, не поставляется.

Если есть библиотека, если она прописана в нужном конфиге (а их может быть несколько; а подключаться может не тот, в котором прописано подключение этого модуля), то копайте под фаервол.

Answer (score 0):

1. Раскомментировать ;extension=php_openssl.dll в php.ini
2. Закинуть php_openssl.dll в папку \usr\local\php5\ext
3. Denwer -> restart