# Выдаёт ошибку в коде

Tags: php, json, потоки-данных, streaming

Здравствуйте! есть код, который должен получать информацию с twitch канала

```
 <?$channelName = htmlspecialchars($_GET['channel'], ENT_QUOTES);

    //Получаем ID здесь http://www.twitch.tv/settings?section=applications
    $clientId = 'dreamhackcs';
    //подставляем значение в переменную online
    $online = 'Online';
    //подставляем значение в переменную offline
    $offline = 'Offline';
    $json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'.strtolower($channelName).'?client_id='.$clientId), true);

    if ($json_array['stream'] != NULL) {
        $channelTitle = $json_array['stream']['channel']['display_name'];
        $streamTitle = $json_array['stream']['channel']['status'];
        $currentGame = $json_array['stream']['channel']['game'];
        $delay = $json_array['stream']['channel']['delay'];
        $logo = $json_array['stream']['channel']['logo'];

        echo "Пользователь: $channelTitle <br> Статус: $online <br> Сейчас в игре: $currentGame <br> Задержка: $delay <br> Логотип: $logo";
    } else {
        echo "$channelName в данный момент $offline />";
    }?>
```

Но вот она выдаёт ошибку:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/?client_id=dreamhackcs) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in V:\home\reg.su\www\index.php on
>   line 10 РІ РґР°РЅРЅС‹Р№ РјРѕРјРµРЅС‚ Offline />

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/222688/denwer-%D0%B8-file-get-contents вот тут есть ответ. думаю подойдёт

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Denwer и file\_get\_contents](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/222688/denwer-%d0%b8-file-get-contents)

Comment: первую проблему я решил

Comment: и переделал вопрос, теперь новая ошибка :D

Comment: запросите через браузер и смотрите на ошибку думаю авторизации не хватает.

Comment: $channelName пуст, т.к. вы обращаетесь к https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/?client_id=dreamhackcs - потому и ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

1. Заходим https://www.twitch.tv/settings/connections
2. Создаём приложение.
3. Настраиваем, указывает откуда будут идти запросы, и получаем Client-ID

   $channelsApi = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/';

   $channelName = 'twitch';

   $clientId = 'axjhfp777tflhy0yjb5sftsil';

   $ch = curl_init();

   curl_setopt_array($ch, array(

   ```
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      'Client-ID: ' . $clientId
   ),
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
   CURLOPT_URL => $channelsApi . $channelName
   ```

   ));

   $response = curl_exec($ch);

   curl_close($ch);

Answer (score 0):

ВЖУХ! и нет проблем

```
<?$channelName = silvername;

        //Получаем ID здесь http://www.twitch.tv/settings?section=applications
        $clientId = 'dzayarr9nbqawy297yopktokswn75a';
        //подставляем значение в переменную online
        $online = 'Online';
        //подставляем значение в переменную offline
        $offline = 'Offline';
        $json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'.strtolower($channelName).'?client_id='.$clientId), true);

        if ($json_array['stream'] != NULL) {
            $channelTitle = $json_array['stream']['channel']['display_name'];
            $streamTitle = $json_array['stream']['channel']['status'];
            $currentGame = $json_array['stream']['channel']['game'];
            $delay = $json_array['stream']['channel']['delay'];
            $logo = $json_array['stream']['channel']['logo'];

            echo "Пользователь: $channelTitle <br> Статус: $online <br> Сейчас в игре: $currentGame <br> Задержка: $delay <br> Логотип: $logo";
        } else {
            echo "$channelName в данный момент $offline />";
        }?>
```