# Не удается выполнить file_get_contents на windows server

Tags: php, windows-server

Скачал php 7.1.3, поместил его в корень диска C

Пытаюсь выполнить такой скрипт:

```
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/file.txt', file_get_contents('https://site.ru/file.txt'));
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

В php.ini строку раскомментировал(сервер перезагружал):

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

P.S. запускаю скрипт такой командой через cmd:

```
php.exe -f C:\folder\script.php
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Конечно, ответ не универсальный, но может тебе поможет
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/222688/denwer-%D0%B8-file-get-contents

Comment: @Cus уже читал. Не помогло.(

Comment: dll файл есть в extension_dir есть?

Comment: extension_dir - переменная в php.ini

Comment: @Cus да, есть, проверял уже

Comment: Попробуйте передать путь для php.ini файла (-c path/to/php.ini) где у вас включено это расширение при запуске через консоль. У PHP это сделано чтобы можно было использовать консольную конфигурацию отдельно от серверной. (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/configuration.file.php)

Comment: убрать .dll из конфига, у вас пытается загрузить php_openssl.dll.dll, и посмотрите в php_ini(), там написано откуда пытается php конфиги грузить